# Can't run android emulator for Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, android-emulator, xamarin.forms

I've got a Xamarin forms app and am using Xamarin Studio on a Mac.

I can debug my app successfully when running on **iOS** emulator, however, my app crashes straight away and doesn't give me a chance to find out what's going on when using the **android** emulator.

An extract of the application output is below. There are several errors like these:

> am start -n
>   "com.aangaba.scl/md57e35e077cd3bd07458f75ce95d82a8df.MainActivity"
>   Starting: Intent {
>   cmp=com.aangaba.scl/md57e35e077cd3bd07458f75ce95d82a8df.MainActivity }
>
> [art] Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) [art] Unexpected CPU
>   variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64 [monodroid] Using override
>   path: /data/user/0/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override** [monodroid]
>   Using override path:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**
>   [monodroid] Trying to load sgen from:
>   /data/user/0/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**/libmonosgen-2.0.so
>   [monodroid] Trying to load sgen from:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**/libmonosgen-2.0.so
>   [monodroid] Trying to load sgen from:
>   /data/app/com.aangaba.scl-1/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so [monodroid]
>   Trying to load sgen from:
>   /data/user/0/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
>   [monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options:
>   --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:56150,embedding=1
>   [Mono] Assembly Loader probing location:
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**/mscorlib.dll'.
>   [Mono] Image addref mscorlib[0x7ffee7e37a80] ->
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**/mscorlib.dll[0x7ffee9c64000]:
>   2 [Mono] AOT module
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**/mscorlib.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/com.aangaba.scl-1/lib/x86_64/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not
>   found
>   [Mono] Assembly System.Runtime[0x7ffee7e57380] added to domain
>   RootDomain, ref_count=1 [Mono] AOT module
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.aangaba.scl/files/.**override**/System.Runtime.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/com.aangaba.scl-1/lib/x86_64/libaot-System.Runtime.dll.so"
>   not found [Mono] AOT module
>   '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86_64/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Runtime.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/com.aangaba.scl-1/lib/x86_64/libaot-System.Runtime.dll.so"
>   not found

It seems that my app files aren't installed on the emulator and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

It reads like you are using the incorrect emulator for the architecture you are targeting. Launch the AVD Manager and create the correct emulators (an x86_64 atom image sounds like the best bet).

There are some instructions for creating the virtual device on the following link:

[Android SDK Emulator in Xamarin Studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/)